# Referencing ItemSource in code

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have a SL4 DataGrid whose ItemsSource is set to a StaticResource pointed to a ViewModel.
I need to get the collection of data items from the DataGrid in a code-behind file.
Since the ItemsSource is an IEnumerable, I thought this would work, but it does not.

IEnumerable listEntities = DataGrid.ItemsSource as MyEntity;

I'm sure that I just have some simple construct wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to set a breakpoint at that line and see if there are any items in the DataGrid.ItemsSource. What does the debugger tell you about the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `IEnumerable listEntities = DataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<MyEntity>;`

Comment: Tried the suggestion and it did not work. I'm getting a NullReferenceException, yet if I skip this part the DataGrid shows the data with no problem. Any other ideas?